# Multiple jobs in selenium scheduler

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'm using Selenium on Firefox. Is it possible to play multiple tests in the Selenium scheduler? 
I put 4 jobs with different time schedules, but, somedays just one of them runs or executes all of them like they are the same job.
Can someone help with this?

Comment: please share your error

Comment: Thanks faheem khan.
Like I said, I put 4 jobs in selenium ide scheduler, but, they don't run and, obviously, don't create the log file.
Do you know if is it possible to put more than one job to execute in Selenium IDE? I've read in other site that is not possible to put more than one job, even putting different time schedules.

Answer (score 0):

I found a "solution" to the problem.

The Selenium IDE run multiple jobs with different time schedule in the same instances. However, it's not possible to generate different log files. Sometimes he mix the files or even don't create any file at all.

So, in my case, I use a VM to execute all the test cases, then I create different users and each one of them executes and creates individuals log files.

I know that this is not the best solution, but it works.